# Divide a list to smaller lists C#

Tags: c#

I'm generating a list using this code :

```
        var Data2 = Data.GroupBy(i => new { i.City, i.County, i.Type })
                                    .Select(group => new { Name = group.Key, Number = group.Count() })
                                    .OrderBy(x => x.Name).ThenByDescending(x => x.Number).ToList();
```

This list has about 5100 records. I want to generate distinct lists with unique City and County. A number of lists or arrays can work for me. Can you give me some ideas for doing that? Thanks.

EDIT :

For example this query returns such a list :

```
    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Bronx, Type = Type A }}, Count = 4 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Bronx, Type = Type B }}, Count = 8 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Bronx, Type = Type C }}, Count = 24 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Manhattan, Type = Type B }}, Count = 43 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Manhattan, Type = Type C }}, Count = 58 }

    { Name = {{ City = Seattle, County  = King County, Type = Type D }}, Count = 43 }

    { Name = {{ City = Seattle, County  = King County, Type = Type A }}, Count = 67 }

    { Name = {{ City = Seattle, County  =    Snohomish County, Type = Type C }}, Count = 67 }
```

I want to make this list to several lists like this :

List 1:

```
    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Bronx, Type = Type A }}, Count = 4 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Bronx, Type = Type B }}, Count = 8 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Bronx, Type = Type C }}, Count = 24 }
```

List 2 :

```
    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Manhattan, Type = Type B }}, Count = 43 }

    { Name = {{ City = New York City, County  = Manhattan, Type = Type C }}, Count = 58 }
```

List 3 :

```
    { Name = {{ City = Seattle, County  = King County, Type = Type D }}, Count = 43 }

    { Name = {{ City = Seattle, County  = King County, Type = Type A }}, Count = 67 }
```

List 4:

```
    { Name = {{ City = Seattle, County  =  Snohomish County, Type = Type C }}, Count = 67 }
```

Comment: Why do you group by `Type`? if you want a unique list for `City` and `County` group by those fields only

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I'm grouping by Type in order to get count for that City, County and Type. I have distinct lists for City and County but I also need count for Type parameter.

Comment: It's not clear. Add some data and expected results

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it:
Its a group within a group

```
var Data2 =
    Data.GroupBy(i => new {i.City, i.County, i.Type})
        .Select(group => new {Name = group.Key, Count = group.Count()})
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        .ThenByDescending(x => x.Count)
        .GroupBy(g => new {g.Name.City, g.Name.County})
        .Select(g => g.Select(g2 => 
            new {Name = new {g.Key.City, g.Key.County, g2.Name.Type}, g2.Count}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I apply `ToList()` to this query. It's taking too long to give `Data2`.

Comment: What if you add also a `.ToList()` after the `ThenByDescending` like your initial query?

Comment: Then it's giving 0 results.